# html highlighting for .leaf files with Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets, leaf

Title (almost) says it all. I'm using Brackets 1.9 as my text editor. Now that I'm playing around with Vapor and using Leaf as a templating language.

I would like to do syntax coloring/predicting in my `.leaf` files while editing them with Brackets. I don't think there is support for the leaf syntax as such, but since `.leaf` files consist of a lot of HTML this would already be a big help.

Anyone who can help me configuring Brackets for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Wiki here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Language-Support) on GitHub that covers what you want. Basically, you do the following:

1. Create a `.brackets.json` file in the root of the project.
2. Add the JSON to configure all the files with `.leaf` to highlight as HTML:

   ```
   {
       "language.fileExtensions": {
           "leaf": "html"
       }
   }
   ```